# list of all validation errors on page post back including hidden fields in multiview

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms

I am working on an .Net Webforms project and on one page there is a multiview that contains many fields that need validation on each view. All have required field validators, but I need to only validate when the user wants to update the saved data, not when they are just looking at it. Because of this the client side doesn't know of the existence of fields from view1 in the multi view when view 5 is the only one visible. Page.isvalid returns false but I need to display all there errors in a validation summary.

Comment: did you try to put all validation controls (including ValidationSummary) in a same ValidationGroup?

Comment: Yes, and that works as long as the fields that are in error are being displayed in the multiview. But it does not display the errors for the "hidden" views.

Comment: be sure to also add the ValidationGroup to the buttons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you really want, I think you mean that you want to display all errors from all the "view" in the ValidationSumary?

Some note: using ValidationGroup for all controls, buttons and validationsumary, put validationsumary outside the views...

The best is to show your code here, but here is a sample of working code that may help you, get this from [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/thread/98273/validation-summary-control-using-in-multiview-control.aspx)

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
            <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
                view 1:&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                &nbsp;<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </asp:View>
             <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
                 view 2 :<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                     ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator2">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </asp:View>
        </asp:MultiView>

    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="submit" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="view2" onclick="Button2_Click" />
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="view1" onclick="Button3_Click" />
```